# jwplayer playAd() for mobile web with googima not working? Any workarounds.

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer6, vast, google-ima

I am trying to call the playAd() function of jwplayer for Google IMA Client in "mobile web". But this function call is having no effect.

This is working in Desktop.

I know from inspecting the page that jwplayer actually injects the google ima sdk js in the page and uses google the sdk to play ads and encapsulates that with jwplayer functions like playAd()

But this is not working on mobile web. maybe because jwplayer doesn't support this for html5.

So, Is there any way to get a handle of some key Google IMA SDK objects like: google.ima.AdDisplayContainer, google.ima.AdsLoader, google.ima.AdsRequest etc.. So that i can use them directly.

I am using the latest version of jwplayer.
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: playAd() only works for IMA in Flash, not HTML5.

Comment: Thanks Ethan for the reply. Is their any way to get a reference of ima objects that is used by jwplayer internally, so that i can use it according to my needs. Thanks again.

Comment: Is it possible to use the VAST client here, or is IMA required? We do not have any public methods for getting any of that information I'm afraid.

Comment: with vast client, the google tags are not working. for google DFP tags to work you need the ima SDK and for that you need to set the client to googima.

Comment: Ah, I see. It was worth a shot. Yeah, playAd for IMA is not yet supported, I'm afraid.